# Piezoelectric polarity

Tags: material-science, piezoelectric

After a few days, I cannot find an answer to this question:

> Besides mechanical stress, is there another way to induce a negative charged surface on quartz?

Note: several scholarly articles kept referring to photons/light but never gave an example or explanation. This is one example of not finding adequate material. Of course, I found other discussions which usually went into silicon and semiconductors. Not what I am looking for.

Comment: I think your question would be better suited for the physics stack exchange.  At EESE, we talk more so about the design of electronic devices.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [triboelectric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect), rub a Teflon rod with a piece of silk, then separate them and touch the rod to the surface of the quartz, and some charge will be transferred to the quartz surface.

Answer (score 0):

Besides mechanical stress, one way to induce a voltage across a [quartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz)-crystal is a change in temperature, since quartz is also a [pyroelectrica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyroelectricity). The crystal structure changes in response to a different temperature, and induces polarization.

This is not always the case for piezoelectrica, since not all piezoelectrica are pyroelectrica:

[image: Relationship between pyro, piezo and ferroelctrica.]

The generated voltage will gradually disappear due to leakage current.